# SharePoint Modal Window on first site view

Tags: sharepoint-2010, modalpopupextender

I need to place a disclaimer on the home page of my 2010 portal site. So when the user first views the site they see a ShaerPoint modal window with a disclaimer message. Once they close the window they can begin browsing the site.

How can I modify this approach so the modal window appears when the page renders verse an onclick event?

```
<a onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event, &quot;http://sitename/Images/image.png&quot;); 
javascript:return false;" href="/images/image.png/" target="_self">Show Image</a>
```

reference: http://erikswenson.blogspot.de/2010/09/ways-to-extend-sharepoint-modal-window.html